# xslt how to add attributes to copy-of

Tags: xslt

I have the following piece of code in my XSLT file:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/root/Algemeen/foto/node()" />
```

In the XML file the node `/root/Algemeen/foto/` holds an HTML image, for example: <img src="somephoto.jpg" />

What I would like to do is to add a fixed width to the image. But the following doesn't work:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/root/Algemeen/foto/node()">
    <xsl:attribute name="width">100</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:copy-of>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`xsl:copy-of` performs a deep copy of the selected node, but doesn't provide an opportunity to alter it.

You will want to use `xsl:copy` and then add additional nodes inside.  `xsl:copy` just copies the node and namespace attributes, but not the regular attributes and child nodes, so you will want to ensure that you `apply-templates` to push the other nodes through as well.  `xsl:copy` does not have a `@select`, it works on the current node, so wherever you were applying the `<xsl:copy-of select="/root/Algemeen/foto/node()" />`
, you will need to change to `<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Algemeen/foto/node()" />` and move the `img` logic into a template.

Something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Algemeen/foto/img"/>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

<!--specific template match for this img -->
    <xsl:template match="/root/Algemeen/foto/img">
      <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="width">100</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
          </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<!--Identity template copies content forward -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```