# Working with XSLT. Sample application

Tags: java, xslt

I want to reproduce [this](http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog) example in Java sample app:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog
```

This is my sample app:

- `input.xml` - contains the content that was shown in w3schools site
- `transform.xslt`- contains the content that was shown in w3schools site
- `output.xml` - just empty file. will be filled by content as xslt-transformation result

All files are locateed in my `/myproject/...resource/myclasspath` directory. 
[I use `getResourceAsStream`])

Here it is, the sample app:

```
public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, TransformerException {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        InputStream xstlStream = TestMain.class.getResourceAsStream("transform.xslt");

        Source xslt = new StreamSource(xstlStream);
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

        InputStream inputStream = TestMain.class.getResourceAsStream("input.xml");

        Source inputSource = new StreamSource(inputStream);

        URL url = TestMain.class.getResource("output.xml");

        transformer.transform(inputSource, new StreamResult(new File(url.toURI())));
    }

}
```

When I start this app, It still does not have any content in `output.xml`. I was exception the same result that was shown on w3schools site.

Basically, for may particular case I just want to add attribute to `<data></data>` tag, to have output like this `<data attr=""></data>`. But first start with this sample app.

Q: Why does it not work?

Comment: Oh.. my God. I got it. Everytime just after I post it here. I was looking for output in my source file directly, but not in compiled one. Hope this will be helpful for someone.

Comment: ok. and answer on my last question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972992/xslt-how-to-add-attributes-to-copy-of

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it so that people know this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: just look at compiled folder, but not to source one. There is output file with expected content.