# XSLT: Positioning of newly added attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

i am copying a xml document and add a attribute to certain nodes 
(see: [xslt how to add attributes to copy-of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972992/xslt-how-to-add-attributes-to-copy-of))

Thing is, my nodes already have some existing attributes, f.e.:

```
<element id="123" dbfield="table">
```

When i add a new attribute, it gets positioned in front of the first attribute, just like that:

```
<element version="default" id="123" dbfield="table">
```

I would prefer to have it as the last attribute, like this:

```
<element  id="123" dbfield="table" version="default">
```

Is there a way to set the position of the new "version"-attribute? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Order of attributes does not matter. What would you like to do exactely?

Comment: All my co-workers are used to that order, so i do not want to change it if not necessary. Some of these values get set manually from to time, that is why i prefer to keep the order. I would like to have the new attribute added as the last one, see the  example.

Comment: @brun0 Which specific processor do you use?

Comment: @michael.hor257k SaxonHE9-2-0-6j

Comment: @brun0 Then I believe my answer will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSLT language does not provide a way to control the order of attributes, because the [XML language specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) states explicitly that the order of attributes is not significant.

Still, most processors will write out the attributes in the order of the  instructions given to them - so you just need to change the order from (presumably, as you did not show your current code):

```
<xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="version">default</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="version">default</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Note that these two template rules have different effect if the existing `element` already has a `version` attribute. When you write two attributes with the same name, the last one wins.

Comment: Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of Saxon (PE and EE) have a serialization property `saxon:attribute-order`. Writing:

```
<xsl:output saxon:attribute-order="id dbfield version"/>
```

will ensure that the attributes matching these names are serialized in the defined order, followed by attributes that are not present in the list.

While it's true that you should never treat attribute order as significant in the sense of causing receiving software to behave differently, I do agree with you that one of the design goals for XML is to be human-readable, and using a consistent attribute order helps to achieve this goal.